# How to add a textbox programmatically to another page using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: .net, vb.net, interop, ms-word, office-interop

I am able to insert a textbox into a Word document using the below code:

```
Dim opProcedures As Word.Shape
opProcedures = oDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 456.75, 24.75)
opProcedures.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Operational Procedures"
```

This adds a textbox to the first page of the document however even when I change the first (top) parameter I am unable to move the textbox onto the second page (only lower down onto the 1st page, any greater values than the height of the first page an it disappears).

How can I get the textbox to appear on the 2nd page of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to provide the missing anchor parameter, using a range which represents a text on the 2nd page (see the docs for `AddTextBox` here:)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171543%28v=office.11%29.aspx

or you have to move the active selection to the second page before calling `AddTextBox`.

Comment: I already had a piece of text on the page so used this for the anchor. Thank You.